# How often do partial solar eclipses of 90% of totality occur in same place?

Tags: solar-eclipse

I know that the mean interval between total eclipses in a single place is about 375 years, which is not surprising given the small band of area of the totality. However, the penumbra of the eclipse partially shadows a much larger area than the totality:

[image]
*Image Credit: NASA Scientific Visualization Studio*

If we were to take a wider area, such as the band of 90% coverage, how many years would there be between eclipses at a single place on average?

Comment: Interesting question, and cool graphic! Where did that image come from by the way? It's usually good to cite the original source.

Comment: As a Q&D approach,  take the width of the totality band, divide by the width of the  90% band, and multiply 375 years by that ratio.  I'm not posting as an answer because it feels like too much of a hack.

Comment: Here some interesting links, but not (yet) an answer: https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEsaros/SEperiodicity.html and http://www.archaeocosmology.org/eng/eclipse.htm